# 'session state is not available in this context' when multiple files in request

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, httpapplication

The code sample at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2527105 is exactly what I need to share sessions between two subdomains.  Only problem is it doesn't work in a real life situation.  It works fine when the ony file being requested is the page itself, but throws an error 'session state is not available in this context' when other files are part of the request, such as if I add stylesheets or javascript files to the page.  The code is generating this error in the "if (context.Session != null &&" line below:

```
void context_PostRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication context = (HttpApplication)sender;
    HttpCookie cookie = context.Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"];

    if (context.Session != null &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Session.SessionID))
    {
        cookie.Value = context.Session.SessionID;
        if (rootDomain != "localhost")
        {
            cookie.Domain = rootDomain;
        }
        cookie.Path = "/";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should give this a title describing the problem rather than asking if people are familiar with the example.

Comment: Okay, edited the title, hopefully that draws in some people who are familiar.

Comment: I tweaked it a bit more.

Comment: As a quick test, wrap your if statement in the following: if(context.Request.Path.ToUpper().IndexOf(".ASPX") > 0) {} to see what happens if you exclude any non-aspx files from this code (i.e. only proceeed if the current request is for an aspx page and not a HTML page or CSS file etc). I'm surprised they are being pushed through the handler though, if that's the problem.

Comment: It does work if I wrap it in that.  I was a bit surprised too that those files were being pushed through the handler.

Comment: Ah, are you hosting in in the inbuilt Visual Studio Web Server? Or is it IIS, and, if so, which version?

Comment: Using the built in VS web server.  Is that part of the problem?  Becasue I can't even get their tiny little sample app to work right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a Try Catch Block, then you can trap for a null value.

```
    private HttpSessionState GetSession(HttpApplication context)
    {
        try
        {
            //On Abadon or Logout this returns "Session state is not available in this context. "
            return context.Session;
        }
        catch (HttpException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```